# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 - gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 5947481

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc

we have a hyperleger fabric network up and running and we have inserted a lot of data in it. When we query all the data, it gives the following error:

> gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4174304: 5747481

How and where can I fix this?

Do I need to paste this "grpc.max_receive_message_length": -1" in the connection profiles for each organization? If so, do I also need to rebuild the whole network or should this change be enough?

The code:

```
    "peers": {
    "peer0.test.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:17051",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\ntestestest...
        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.test.com",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.test.com",
            "grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize": 104857600

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which SDK are you using?  Node or Java?

Comment: I am using the Java SDK within a Java spring boot only to do CRUD operations. The network is created by using shell scripts (look for the new 2.0 github example project). The chaincode is written in Go.

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you already solve?

Answer (score 2):

Given you are using the Java SDK, you need to set the `grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize` property.  I'm not sure if this will work in the connection profile, but you can definitely add it to the properties for the peer or orderer in your actual code:

```
peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 90000000);
```

The setting is in bytes.  The max message size Fabric supports is ~100MB.

Comment: I am not using theJava SDK to setup the network, everything is done via shell scripting (like their example) and the go language for the chaincode. The JAVA SDK is only used for crud operations. I also have edited my post, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: right ... what I am suggesting above is adding the property to the peer properties in your client when using the SDK.  You load the config file and then manually add properties.   I'm not sure why your connection profile is not working

Comment: Do you have any example how to achieve this? Because I only used the SDK for CRUD functionalities. Hope you can help me out with this one.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/release-1.4/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java#L864-L870